# Issues with Bower on Ubuntu

Tags: node.js, task, bower

Currently having issues with using Bower on Ubuntu

I attempt to use bower install, bower init and I am advised not to use sudo, but when I do I get the following error

> bower EACCES        EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/xxxxxx/html/wp-content/themes/xxxxxxxx/bower.json'
>
> Stack trace:
>   Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/var/www/xxxxxx/html/wp-content/themes/xxxxxxxx/bower.json'
>       at Error (native)
>
> Console trace:
>   Error
>       at StandardRenderer.error (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/renderers/StandardRenderer.js:81:37)
>       at Logger. (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/bin/bower.js:110:26)
>       at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>       at Logger.emit (events.js:169:7)
>       at Logger.emit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/bower-logger/lib/Logger.js:29:39)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/commands/index.js:48:20
>       at _rejected (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:844:24)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:870:30
>       at Promise.when (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:1122:31)
>       at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/bower/lib/node_modules/q/q.js:788:41)
>   System info:
>   Bower version: 1.7.9
>   Node version: 4.2.6
>   OS: Linux 4.4.0-36-generic x64

The only thing that works is the following `sudo bower install --allow-roots`

Is there any way around this ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to have permission to the directory you are trying to install files in. So you have to use bower as a user who has access to this folder (eg `www-data` on Ubuntu: `sudo -u www-data bower install`)